# Make function work on each element separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress element that will show post excerpts in a carousel. To demonstrate what I am doing I've created a github repository with a html version of the carousel.

https://github.com/dingo-d/Post-Excerpt-Carousel

The carousel is working mostly fine, but I have an issue that I don't understand where it's coming from. When I have one carousel on a page, all is working fine. But what if there are two or more on the same page?

What happens is that when you click on next icon, the slider where you've clicked it will move to the left, and the classes will switch from one item to another list item (active class), but those classes will move on all carousels on the site (there is a html file with multiple carousels on repo).

I've created a function that will manage the movement and clicking, and I'm calling it like this:

```
$('.post_excerpt_carousel').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    post_excerpt_positioning($this);
});
```

I've done it like this, so that I can toggle it on resize also.

I've created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mugmjsdy/1/) but it's easier to see the repository and download the examples folder (better visibility).

How to prevent the classes switching on all carousels, and make them switch only when I click on a certain carousel?

EDIT: Codepen preview: http://codepen.io/dingo_d/pen/doNyMw

Comment: Why are you doing this?
`var $ul = $(this).parents('.post_excerpt_carousel').find('ul');`
it goes back to the root of all your sliders.

Comment: You should add the `wordpress` tag to your question.

Comment: romuleald I honestly have no idea why I did this. I originally created this 6 months ago, but I recently realized it was crappy, so I'm fixing it. I removed it in a new fiddle and in the repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was on line 61 in main.js :

```
var $a = $('.active');
```

You are selecting all the elements having `.active` class.

You can fix this just by replacing this line with :

```
var $a = $('.active', $carousel);
```

This way, it will select only the `.active` found inside `$carousel`